# Why does my org-mode file is showing some ^M and \303\251 characters

Tags: character-encoding, org-mode

I'm quite new to org-mode (6 months) but I must confess that  I cannot envisage my working day without it now, as a note-taking tool and amy genda.
I'm quite lost as since a couple of days, my file shows some ^M and \303\251 everywhere. What is weird is that it didn't happen before... I must precise that I write in mixed English and french, therefore I use special characters like "é, è, ç", typical in french.
I assume it deals with the encoding system, that's why I went through other questions. But I can't find any workaround.
My .emacs contains this code since the very beginning

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

My emacs version in 26.2 and I'm on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am having the same problem on Emacs 25.2.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  It seems to have started a day or two ago.  My .emacs file has nothing in it about coding systems.

Comment: `^M` (<Ctrl> + M) is `U+000D` _Carriage Return (CR)_ and `\303\251` is [octal escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6). `\303\251` = byte sequence `0xC3`,`0xA9` = UTF-8 byte sequence for character `é` (`U+00E9` _Latin Small Letter E With Acute_). Not much more to say without a [mcve].